# Two <div> containers side by side

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding placing two <div> containers side by side.

The code should later look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="leftColumn">navigation</div>
<div class="rightColumn">content</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9NFDS/

Question:

Which of the two provided examples is more W3C conformant? Which way is better for creating a distance between the two container?

Comment: That means that i can use both of them or do you have a better idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target the browser support for lower versions for IE (like IE7 or even lower) you need to work with the second approach (padding).

There will be an issue with your first approach as one of your container is left floated and one is right so the height of the parent div (wrapperExampleOne) will collapse and will result in 0px (which should be equal to the height of its children).

The better approach that works with most of the browsers is to use margin. An example is mentioned here in the third example of your modified fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9NFDS/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperExampleThree">
    <div class="leftColumn">
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapperExampleThree
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.wrapperExampleThree .leftColumn
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
}
.wrapperExampleThree .rightColumn
{
    width: 650px;
    margin-left:50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If  i don't want to support older browsers is it okay to use example one? What would you do in this case?

Comment: You need to use a clear div at the end of the parent div. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P5t3Z/

Comment: Ups. Yes i have this already in my code but forgot to post it.

Answer (score 0):

i think 1st one.

```
<div class="wrapperExampleOne">
<div class="leftColumn">
</div>
<div class="rightColumn">
</div>
</div>
```

Making distance is common in today era. just like facebook, youtube, google.